# How to have a forum in my Django website?

Tags: python, django, forum, phpbb

I want to have a forum on my Django website and I prefer to use the third-party packages.
After doing some research I saw some packages like machina and Spirit and PyBBM

https://django-machina.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html

The question is how can I make any of these packages to use another language like persian?(It's RTL)
Or can I use the other methods like phpbb in my django project?

Comment: That'll depend on the specific package you choose. The one you link to appears to use Django's i18n system and even has an incomplete localisation to Arabic already: https://github.com/ellmetha/django-machina/blob/main/machina/locale/ar/LC_MESSAGES/django.po. You should be able to add your own Persian PO files as necessary.